# Running Total in Chart in Header in Crystal Reports

Tags: charts, crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

Can I place a chart in a header section with a RT as the "show value" and have it calculate the RT properly?

The RT runs before the Chart, but the RT is calculated on the 3rd pass as does the chart after the header sections are run.

Things seem to be working

A bit confused by all this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reliably use a Running Total anywhere except in a footer or detail section. As a rule, RTs are calculated during the printing pass, that is to say, very late in the report's rendering. The same goes for using print-time variables/formulas. They might show a value in the report but the data will essentially be meaningless.

But you *can* use a basic summary function in the header like `Sum()` or `Count()`.

Comment: Does this mean you can not put a chart in a header as-well?

Comment: A chart can be used in a header as long as its data source is not a RT or print-time formula.